# searchings rows from table

Tags: java

i want to select particular rows from the JTable which contains a particular string..  please help me for this..

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details than this

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
void selectMatchingRows(JTable table, String regex) 
{    
  for (int row = 0; row < table.getModel().getRowCount(); row++) 
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < table.getModel().getColumnCount(); col++) 
    {
      if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row, col).toString().matches(regex)) 
      {
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row, row);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Making sure the `ListSelectionModel.selectionMode` is `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`.

Answer (score 0):

Call [JTable.getModel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getModel%28%29) then just loop through using [TableModel.getValueAt](http://getValueAt)